# How to create link to a data-filter element

Tags: javascript, html

Please tell me how to make a link in the menu to the button with data-filter, so that when you click on the link in the menu, the page scrolls to the place with the buttons and activates it. (The buttons are responsible for managing the filter on mixitup js)

-----------------top of the sitetop of the site--------------

```
<a href="#">text link</a>
<a href="#">text link</a>
<a href="#">text link</a>
```

-----------------bottom of the site-----------------

```
<button type="button" data-filter=".sites">text button</button>
<button type="button" data-filter=".contextual ">text button</button>
<button type="button" data-filter=".targeting">text button</button>
```

````
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"').forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let href = this.getAttribute('href').substring(1);
      const scrollTarget = document.getElementById(href);      
      const topOffset = 160;
      const elementPosition = scrollTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      const offsetPosition = elementPosition - topOffset;
      window.scrollBy({
          top: offsetPosition,
          behavior: 'smooth'
      });
  });
});```
````

Comment: Could you post an attempt to your solution, just a hint, you cannot do this natively with HTML and would need to use JS to scroll and click the button depending on what link has been clicked.

Comment: with scrolling to the element as a whole, everything is clear, but with a click on the button, not really ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step you need to do is to identify which button to click. Now assuming your href is of the type `"#sites-filter"`. Then the line `let href = this.getAttribute('href').substring(1);` in your jQuery would yield `sites-filter`.

You should then add `ids` to your buttons to identify which link has been clicked, naming them the same as your `href` would eliminate the need for extra variables.

After your `window.scrollBy()` function you can simply, select the button by `href` using

`const button = document.getElementById(href)` and then running a `button.click()` to click the button.